# How to get a list of lists in Typesafe Config

Tags: java, list, config, typesafe

I have a [typesafe config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config) with a list of lists. Basically what I'm trying to do is to extract a multi-map.

```
myconfig {
  values = [
      [ 'key1', 'value1'],
      [ 'key1', 'value2'],
      [ 'key2', 'value2'],
      [ 'key2', 'value3'],
    ]
```

Workaround I has to use:

```
myconfig {
  values = {
    key1 : [ 'value1' , 'value2' ]
    key2 : [ 'value2' , 'value3' ]
  }
}
```

Is there a nice way of extracting the original list of lists? All functions expect a path, so once I extract 'values' there seem to be no direct way of accessing an inner list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `getList(String path)` on the `Config` object to get back a `ConfigList` object.

**Java:**

```
config.getList("path.to.keys").stream()
  .map(configValue -> (ArrayList) configValue.unwrapped())
  .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

A `ConfigList` contains `ConfigValue` instances. In this case, the typesafe people represent the list internally as an ArrayList so you have to make the cast when you unwrap the `ConfigValue` object.

The snippet above returns a List of List. If you want to flatten the list, use flatMap instead of Map and return a stream in the lambda.

**Edit**

Here's the equivalent Scala:

```
  import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
  val keys: Map[String, String] = config.getList("path.to.keys")
    .map(configValue =>
      configValue.unwrapped().asInstanceOf[ArrayList[String]]
    )
    .foldLeft(Map[String, String]())( (map, list) =>
      map + (list(0) -> list(1))
    )
```

Comment: Found this wasn't quite sufficient if all the types in the list are not the same. Say for example you defined a list of double lists and in your config it was: [[3, 4.3], ...] the first number would be parsed as an integer and you end up with a ClassCastException when accessing as a double. So in this case I had to me more specific:    cv.unwrapped().asInstanceOf[util.ArrayList[Number]].asScala.toList.map(_.doubleValue())